# A question related to a deducing a result related to degree of a polynomial

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

Consider the following expression.

$P* = \prod_{\deg P \leq \zeta} P$

So, $\deg P* = \sum\limits_{\deg P \leq \zeta} \deg P = \sum\limits_{j \leq \zeta } j π(j) $ .

I understand  how $\deg P* = \sum\limits_{\deg P\leq  \zeta} \deg P $.

But I don't know how $\sum\limits_{\deg P \leq \zeta} \deg P = \sum\limits_{j \leq \zeta } j π(j) $ .

Author has not mentioned what $j$ is but he writes $a= \sum\limits_{j\leq 0} a_j t^j \in F_q[t]$ in previous paragraph.

Can you please help me with that.

For more details please see:[http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~rudnick/courses/sieves2015.html](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Erudnick/courses/sieves2015.html)  See page 6 of Lecture 6 ( Squarefrees over a function field) It is taken from these notes. Lemma 5.1

Comment: Is the product over all polynomials in $F_q[t]$ with deg $\leq \zeta$?  Shouldn't the answer be a function of $q$?

Comment: @JairTaylor Also, next step is $\sum_{j \leq \zeta} j π(j) \ leq \frac{ q^{zeta} -1} {1- 1/q} $  
which also I am struck on  but  as I am struck on previous step , I thought if I can deduce that Or get help with that , then it will help me in this step also.

Comment: Well you still haven't answered my question or defined the question very properly so I can't help you. What is $\pi(x)$? Prime-counting function?

Comment: @Jair Taylor yes it's prime counting function. Yes the product is over all polynomials  in $F_q[t] $ with $ deg \leq \zeta$ . I am really sorry you had trouble understanding it. I hope it's clear now. If you have any other question, kindly comment. Thanks!

Comment: It can't be true as stated since the right-hand side is not a function of $q$ and the degree of this polynomial changes depending on $q$ since there are more polynomials in the product as $q$ increases. Perhaps something here is a q-analog in disguise? More context is needed to understand this.

Comment: @JairTaylor http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~rudnick/courses/sieves2015.html  See page 6 of Lecture 6 ( Squarefrees over a function field) It is taken from these notes. Lemma 5.1

Comment: Thank you, it makes a little bit more sense to me now.  I think $\pi(j)$ should actually be $\pi_q(j)$ here, the number of monic prime polynomials of degree $j$, which is indeed a function of $q$.  I also think the product is perhaps over only prime polynomials $P$.  However I'm not sure where the factor of $j$ comes from in the formula.